# Predefined Header for Global Includes

Tags: c++

I am currently abstracting OpenGL in C++ and I was just wondering if a certain practice I am doing is considered clean and efficient or the complete opposite. I have a header file which is included in close to almost every single header file for the abstraction called "pd.h" and in this file I include everything my program needs as such:

```
#pragma once
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/type_ptr.hpp>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
```

Is this a very unclean and inefficient way for structuring my code? Because this is just how I've taught myself to do things and for some reason looking at it now it looks abit dodgy, and if it is not a good practice could someone explain why I shouldn't be doing this?

Comment: If you need all those header files everywhere, then it might be a good idea. Otherwise if most of your source files only need one or two of them then it's not a good idea. Mostly it's a matter of personal preference though (or corporate coding style).

Comment: Ok, makes sense, so unused header files which are included into another header file does that reduce performance or increase size of compiled binaries?

Comment: That strategy is going to seriously hurt your compile times as the code grows. Try to only *include what you use* everywhere, both in headers and source files and prefer forward declarations over includes when you can.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is something that works, but it has two drawbacks, assuming you use a build system which compiles each `.cpp` file into its own `.o` file and only later links these into the executable.

1. Each time your `pd.h` file changes, all including files need to be recompiled. This means that your whole project has to be recompiled when you change this header. If you know that this file will not change often, then this is not a big drawback for a small project.
2. Build time is increased for each `.cpp` file because all those header files need to be processed, even though they are not needed. Compilers can precompile headers ([check out for VS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/szfdksca.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)), though this is not part of the ISO C++ standard. Not including headers that are not used is an approach which is simpler to use and scales better.

   The size of the executable will not change, nor the performance of the resulting application. Just the compilation time is increased.

So instead have the include only when you really need it. Is it sufficient to have it in the `.cpp` file? Do so. Only if it needs to be included in a header file, do so.

Sometimes you can get away with a forward declaration only. This is the case when the compiler does not need to know the size of the object because you are only defining a pointer to it in the current header.

When you use something, this is the order that I would try:

1. Include that header in the source file only
2. Use a forward declaration in the header file (might need to keep the include in the source file)
3. Include that header in the header file

There is a header `iosfwd` which has forward declarations for the `iostream` header, which can be helpful if you just provide overloads for `operator<<` for your class. These only take `std::ostream &` and therefore the compiler does not need to know the size.

Comment: It's worth mentioning precompiled headers

Comment: @Raxvan: I have added a few words about doing this. I have never actually done this because it seemed like a big hassle and is compiler dependent.

Comment: it is, however somethines that saves you ages in compile times.

Comment: Add a few words about how forward declarations can often be used to avoid an include entirely :-)

Comment: @Raxvan it (precompiled headers) can also sometimes lead to hard to diagnose compiler errors and hidden dependencies. I personally avoid them and instead prefer judicious use of forward declarations and having each file explicitly include what it needs, no more, no less and try not to ever rely on transitively included files.

Comment: @Jesper Juhl yes, every approach has it's downsides, the entire include system is kind of a pain and whatever should be used to speed up compilation times depends on the problems, project size & structure, tools, team, etc.

Comment: Using a universal header **can** increase the size of the executable and slow it down. `<iostream>`, for example, requires that the standard streams are constructed before any user code touches them and that the streams don't get destroyed until all user code has finished with them. There are compiler hooks for doing this, but a fully generic library puts an initializer object into each translation unit that uses the header; the initializer object gets constructed at program startup, and the more initializer objects you have, the more the program thrashes code pages at startup.